# PIL change color channel intensity

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to make a color picker, which recolors a png texture while preserving transparency in python3.
I only want the brighter parts of the image to be recolored, but also keep the gradient.
The only option the I could think of was to adjust the color channel intensity, however I did not find anything like that in the PIL docs.
How do I change the color channel intensity? My PNG texture is loaded in ARGB mode and can be found >>[here](https://github.com/9hax/midRenderResources/raw/master/keys/keyshape_a.png)<<.

Original Image:

[image]

Comment: There is the HSL format, if that's of interest to you - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageColor.html?highlight=hsl. Does modifying the Saturation of the colours sound like what you're after?

Comment: @MarkSetchell actually, i wanted the white part to be recolored, not the black part. but this looks good. how do i do that using PIL?

Comment: seems like the stackoverflow app only notifies you for comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dreamt up an approach for this:

- Extract and save the Alpha/transparency channel
- Convert the image, minus Alpha, to HSV colourspace and save the V (lightness)
- Get a new Hue (and possibly Saturation) from your Colour Picker
- Synthesize a new Hue channel, and a new Saturation channel of 255 (fully saturated)
- Merge the new Hue, Saturation and original V (lightness) to a 3 channel HSV image
- Convert the HSV image back to RGB space
- Merge the original Alpha channel back in

That looks like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open and ensure it is RGB, not palettised
img = Image.open("keyshape.png").convert('RGBA')

# Save the Alpha channel to re-apply at the end
A = img.getchannel('A')

# Convert to HSV and save the V (Lightness) channel
V = img.convert('RGB').convert('HSV').getchannel('V')

# Synthesize new Hue and Saturation channels using values from colour picker
colpickerH, colpickerS = 10, 255
newH=Image.new('L',img.size,(colpickerH))
newS=Image.new('L',img.size,(colpickerS))

# Recombine original V channel plus 2 synthetic ones to a 3 channel HSV image
HSV = Image.merge('HSV', (newH, newS, V))

# Add original Alpha layer back in
R,G,B = HSV.convert('RGB').split()
RGBA = Image.merge('RGBA',(R,G,B,A))

RGBA.save('result.png')
```

With `colpickerH=10` you get this (try putting `Hue=10` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp)):

[image]

With `colpickerH=120` you get this (try putting `Hue=120` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp)):

[image]

---

Just for fun, you can do it exactly the same without writing any Python, just at the command line with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and available for macOS and Windows:

```
# Split into Hue, Saturation, Lightness and Alpha channels
convert keyshape.png -colorspace hsl -separate ch-%d.png

# Make a new solid Hue channel filled with 40, a new solid Saturation channel filled with 255, take the original V channel (and darken it a little), convert from HSL to RGB, copy the Alpha channel from the original image
convert -size 73x320 xc:gray40 xc:white \( ch-2.png -evaluate multiply 0.5 \) -set colorspace HSL -combine -colorspace RGB ch-3.png -compose copyalpha -composite result.png
```

Yes, I could do it as a one-liner, but it would be harder to read.