# Creating an Image in Python from a list of pixel values.(Pillow)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am working with the PIL library. I need to change the intensity of each colour channel in an image. ( I.E cut the whole B values in half) To do that i have iterated over every pixel and saved their values in a list.

```
list_1=[]
for u in range(contact_sheet.height):
    for i in range(contact_sheet.width):
        ppx=Image.Image.getpixel(contact_sheet,(i,u))
        list_1.append(ppx)
```

I have ended up with a single list of tuples with over 1 million pixel values in it. I am planning to iterate over it (edit: as the values are in tuples i couldn't change them) and change the colour values with a loop. My question is, how can i re-convert it into an image? Also I have thought of using numpy array but I'm not so sure about it. Any help would be great.

Comment: You have almost certainly already gone wrong if you are processing images in Python with a `for` loop... and doubly so if you have made a list of pixels since each one is then an object with its own memory allocation and a whole bunch of needless management. There are 3 much better ways of doing exactly what you ask here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323838/2836621

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
list_1=[]
for u in range(contact_sheet.height):
    l = []
    for i in range(contact_sheet.width):
        ppx=Image.Image.getpixel(contact_sheet,(i,u))
        l.append(ppx)
    list_1.append(l)
resultImage = Image.fromarray(np.array(list_1,dtype="uint8"))
resultImage.show()
```

---

In [effbot document](http://www.effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.load),it shows that `Image.load()` is faster than `getpixel()`.So you could use:

```
pix = contact_sheet.load()
list_1=[]
for u in range(contact_sheet.height):
    l = []
    for i in range(contact_sheet.width):
        ppx=pix[i,u]
        l.append(ppx)
    list_1.append(l)
```