# Pillow changing the RGB value of a picture does not work

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am trying to scale the rgb value of a image.

The way I learnt is by doing `getpixel` and `putpixel` for every pixel.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance
from PIL import ImageFont,ImageDraw

# read image and convert to RGB
image=Image.open("readonly/msi_recruitment.gif")
image=image.convert('RGB')

# build a list of 9 images which have different brightnesses
images=[]
intensity = [0.1, 0.5, 0.9]
channel=[0,1,2] 

for c in channel:
    for i in intensity:
        newImage = PIL.Image.new(image.mode, (image.width, image.height+100))
        newImage.paste(image,(0,0))
        
        text="channel {} intensity {}".format(c, i)
        font = ImageFont.truetype(r'readonly/fanwood-webfont.ttf', 75)  
        Draw=ImageDraw.Draw(newImage)
        Draw.text((10,470), text, fill="white", font=font, align="left")
        
        
        for row in range(image.height):
            for col in range(image.width):
                p = image.getpixel((col, row)) # p as RGB pixel values
                
                if channel == 0:
                    newImage.putpixel((col, row), (int(p[0]*i),p[1],p[2]))
                elif channel == 1:
                    newImage.putpixel((col, row), (p[0],int(p[1]*i),p[2]))    
                elif channel == 2:
                    newImage.putpixel((col, row), (p[0],p[1],int(p[2]*i)))    
        
        images.append(newImage)
```

However, It did not work, the pixels' RGB did not change.

1. What is wrong with my codes?
2. Is there a way to scale the RGB values of a picture as a whole instead of looping through pixel by pixel?

Comment: There are 3 possibilities here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323838/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your code, change `channel` to `c` like this:

```
if c == 0:
    newImage.putpixel((col, row), (int(p[0]*i),p[1],p[2]))
elif c == 1:
    newImage.putpixel((col, row), (p[0],int(p[1]*i),p[2]))    
elif c == 2:
    newImage.putpixel((col, row), (p[0],p[1],int(p[2]*i)))
```

To see other ways to do it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59320564/how-to-access-and-change-color-channels-using-pil/59323838#59323838) by Mark Setchell.