# Segmentation Fault when using PIL Image.merge

Tags: python, image, segmentation-fault, python-imaging-library, conda

I have an image that is 600x600 RGB pixels and I would like to create a new image that has the RGB channels transformed from the original image as follows: `(R, G, B) -> (R-1.4*B, G, B)`. I am using absolute value to enforce only positive RGB values. Here is my code to accomplish this which runs into segfault:
`

```
            r, g, b = original.split()                 #split image into (r, g, b) channels

            r = abs(np.array(r)-1.4*np.array(b))       #apply transformation
            
            r = Image.fromarray(r)                     #revert r to PIL Image object
            
            result = Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b))     #merge channels to create new image

            result.show()
```

`

Running the code outputs:

`zsh: segmentation fault  /Users/arjunchandra/miniconda3/envs/bbox_env/bin/python`

The segfault disappears when I comment out the call to Image.merge - I am not sure why this. If anyone has any advice as to why the segfault may be occurring and how to go about resolving it or examining memory please let me know or if you can suggest alternate approach to do the transformation?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323838/22789864) approach gave a couple of ideas for other ways to transform the image but for the matrix approach I am not sure how to use absolute value of (R-1.4B) and I doubt converting the image to numpy array and changing every pixel RGB manually will be efficient as I have many images that I need to do this transformation to.

Comment: This is a bug report to file against PIL, not a question that can be answered here. The problem is clearly in the library's C code and not in your code, even if there are other problems in your code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Do you really think it's a bug in PIL if OP tries to combine a float array with 2 uint8 arrays to make an array of 3 uint8 RGB values? Seems a bit harsh to expect PIL to check everything.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes; it knows what the element types are. It should be able to do the same kinds of checks that Numpy did when it subtracted a floating-point number from the elements of a uint8 array and then multiplied those results elementwise with another uint8 array.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel casting explicitly to uint8 fixed the segfault in the end

Comment: Weird. A valid workaround ,but still something I would expect PIL to be able to handle. Or at least raise a Python exception rather than letting the C code crash.

Answer (score 1):

The value for the red channel is landing outside the bounds for the PIL object (0-255). You'll need to clip the values to keep them within bounds:

```
r = Image.fromarray(r.clip(0, 255))
```

Comment: I am still getting segfault error unfortunately

Comment: Try `r = Image.fromarray(r.clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8))`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I still think this should be reported against PIL (if there isn't already an outstanding issue); but given that that apparently works, it's worth writing up as an answer (including some explanation/investigation if possible). Worth noting that the `astype` is what's preventing the segfault; using `clip` first just avoids numeric overflow in the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Kudos and upvotes to @MSiddons for spotting the core of the problem - namely that the subtraction pushes the result outside the range of `np.uint8` and it is necessary to clip the result to the correct range.

A further complication is that the multiplication with a float (1.4) caused the resulting red band to become a floating point image, which cannot be merged back with the original green and blue bands which are of type `np.uint8`, so an additional cast is required.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Create a purpley image such that B exceeds R
im = Image.new('RGB', (256,256), '#800090')
```

[image]

```
# Split image into constituent bands
r, g, b = im.split()

# Do the maths
r = abs(np.array(r)-1.4*np.array(b))

# Crucial line... force back to np.uint8
r = Image.fromarray(r.astype(np.uint8))

# Problem solved
result = Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b))
```

Now we can check the result:

```
print(result.getpixel((0,0)))

(73, 0, 144)
```

and

```
red (73) = original red (0x80) - 1.4 * blue (0x90)
```